# How do I replicate autohotkey hotstrings in Chrome OS

Tags: autohotkey, google-chrome-os, cr-48

Google gave me a Cr-48 about a month ago. I like it. Its simple and powerful. The temptation to fuss and muss has been removed. However, one of the things I miss a lot is hotstrings that I set up in autohotkey. So for instance typing "asap" will autoexpand to "as soon as possible" no matter what software I am in. I cannot do that in Chrome OS. Google Docs has something under tools>preferences>automatic substitution but that is only specific to Google Docs. I want to have hotstrings everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Popchrom](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/iinhokidgfoomcighckbjmlcndbjmomp)

> Save time and effort with Popchrom by creating your own shortcuts for text phrases! Whether it's a simple email signature or several paragraphs of a standard response, you'll love how easy it is to use Popchrom to avoid typing the same thing over and over.

*Note: I haven't tried this on my Cr-48 yet*

Comment: Thanks Popchrom looks as if it will do the job. But wait, is there a way to export my autohotkey script into popchrom. What would really be cool would be if popchrome could autosyncronize my autohotkey script which is stored in dropbox.